# @color/gray “Validates resource references inside Android XML files”

Tags: android, colors, xml-drawable

I followed the directions on https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ to make a splash screen for my app, but in my background_splash.xml file, the code:

`<item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>`

returns the message “Validates resource references inside Android XML files”.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Update with code:

background_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

SplashActivity.java:

```
package PACKAENAME;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="PACKAGENAME">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what is wrong without seeing the rest of your code. Does the Github project from that blog run?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure what exactly your asking, but when I remove that line of code,  the splash page does run, just without the background color. Also if you would like I can update the question with my code.

Comment: Yes, Please share code of background_splash.xml

Comment: That blog has a link to Github with the final result. Does that run or does the error still happen? There is no reason to copy and paste all the code from the blog into your own project other than to learn iteratively

Comment: I am also using suggested code by bignerd and its working properly for me.

Comment: I believe I found the problem which was the values/colors.xml file which needed a line stating what hex "gray" was.

Comment: @CarterRoeser have you defined the colour `gray` in your `colors.xml` ?

Comment: Are you getting lint warning on following line android:drawable="@color/white" or at this line  ndroid:src="@drawable/splash"

Comment: I havent ran a new build yet, but I was also having a problem with there being two versions off the app when installing the apk, one with the splash and one without it, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @SagarTrehan The main problem is solved now

Comment: those two version has same applicationId? If they are having same applicationId then one will automaticallu update another

Comment: They are the exact same in details and in code, the only difference is the splash screen. I found that this may have to do with the activity name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add value to color in your color.xml like below

```
 <color name="grey">#6E6E6E</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an android developer so when the correct answer says to

> add value to color in your color.xml like below

I don't exactly know what that means.

What it means is. Go to this path inside your android app

```
app/src/main/res/values/
```

and create or use the file called "colors.xml". Then add the grey value to it (or any other color value you need)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="grey">#6E6E6E</color>
    </resources>
```

When using the custom color make sure to use

```
<item android:drawable="@color:grey" />
```

instead of android colors

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/custom_color" />
```